# How to display single hightchart bar graph in multiple container/selector?

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to display the same bar graph in multiple div container on a single page. For some reason (without throwing any error message) highchart does not display the graph in any container.

I have created a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5n92jjpn/) for this case.

```
$('#container,#container2').highcharts({ /*....*/ })
```

Since, there are no errors I cannot seem to figure out how to fix it.

One thing I can think of is to have that function multiple times for each container, but I don't think that is really a solution.

Please guide.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one variable and pass that variable as a paramter each time you initialize highcharts, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enlightenmedia/5n92jjpn/1/)

```
$highchartOpts = {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
    },
    .....
};
$('#container2').highcharts($highchartOpts);
$('#container').highcharts($highchartOpts);
```